# Numpy argmin() to find the nearest tuple

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an array of tuples, I need to find the tuple from that array that is the closes to a given tuple(element wise), that is by the absolute value difference between each element of these two tuples. The array of tuples is like:

```
array_of_tuples = [(0.0, 6.5, 1),
     (0.0, 6.5, 4.5),
     (0.0, 6.5, 8.0),
     (0.0, 13.5, 1),
     (0.0, 13.5, 4.5),
     (0.0, 13.5, 8.0),
     (0.0, 21.0, 1),
     (0.0, 21.0, 4.5),
     (0.0, 21.0, 8.0),
     (7.0, 6.5, 1),
     (7.0, 6.5, 4.5),
     (13.5, 21.0, 8.0)]
```

While the query tuple is `(13.1, 20.3, 8.4)`

However doing: `np.argmin(np.abs(array_of_tuples - (13.1, 20.3, 8.4)))`

gives `8`, while if I print the result without np.argmin() I clearly see that it is the last element in the array that has the least difference with the given tuple.

Comment: I get `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'tuple'` on your last `np.argmin` example. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: from math import dist; ans=min([j[::-1] for j in enumerate([dist(i, dst) for i in array_of_tuples])])[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider all coordinates and aggregate them into a **single** number (per row).

Compute the sum of squares and get the (arg)min of that:

```
np.argmin(((array_of_tuples - (13.1, 20.3, 8.4))**2).sum(axis=1))
```

Output: `11`

Intermediate before `argmin`:

```
array([416.81, 377.26, 362.21, 272.61, 233.06, 218.01, 226.86, 187.31,
       172.26, 282.41, 242.86,   0.81])
```

As suggested by @MadPhysicist, you can also use [`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/.html) to compute the [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) per row:

```
np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(array_of_tuples-(13.1, 20.3, 8.4), axis=1))
```

Comment: `np.linalg.norm`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes that's another possibility, I used the sum of squares as it's close to the original approach and might be easier to understand why OP's approach failed. I'll add this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What it does is correct. See step by step

```
import numpy as np
array_of_tuples = [(0.0, 6.5, 1),
     (0.0, 6.5, 4.5),
     (0.0, 6.5, 8.0),
     (0.0, 13.5, 1),
     (0.0, 13.5, 4.5),
     (0.0, 13.5, 8.0),
     (0.0, 21.0, 1),
     (0.0, 21.0, 4.5),
     (0.0, 21.0, 8.0),
     (7.0, 6.5, 1),
     (7.0, 6.5, 4.5),
    (13.5, 21.0, 8.0)]
array_of_tuples = np.array(array_of_tuples)

sub = array_of_tuples -  (13.1, 20.3, 8.4)
print(sub)

'''
output:
subtracted (13.1, 20.3, 8.4)
[[-13.1 -13.8  -7.4]
 [-13.1 -13.8  -3.9]
 [-13.1 -13.8  -0.4]
 [-13.1  -6.8  -7.4]
 [-13.1  -6.8  -3.9]
 [-13.1  -6.8  -0.4]
 [-13.1   0.7  -7.4]
 [-13.1   0.7  -3.9]
 [-13.1   0.7  -0.4]
 [ -6.1 -13.8  -7.4]
 [ -6.1 -13.8  -3.9]
 [  0.4   0.7  -0.4]]
 '''

ab = np.abs(sub)
print(ab)
'''
negatives are made into positives
output:
[[13.1 13.8  7.4]
 [13.1 13.8  3.9]
 [13.1 13.8  0.4]
 [13.1  6.8  7.4]
 [13.1  6.8  3.9]
 [13.1  6.8  0.4]
 [13.1  0.7  7.4]
 [13.1  0.7  3.9]
 [13.1  0.7  0.4]
 [ 6.1 13.8  7.4]
 [ 6.1 13.8  3.9]
 [ 0.4  0.7  0.4]]
 '''

n = np.argmin(ab)
print(n)

#output 8
#Because no axis given. 0.4 is the smallest number. its index is 8 if array is converted into single dimension
```

Here no axis is given. And 0.4 is the smallest number and first occurence. its index is 8 if array is converted into single dimension

Comment: Thank you, I tried with both `axis=1` and `axis=0` both did not give the right result